# how to toggle between two images using next and prev button?

Tags: android

I have 2 pictures in drawable. What I want to do is show the first image with a small "next" button and when next button is clicked the other image should be displayed with a "prev" button. And now when the prev button is clicked the first image should be displayed with "next" button on it. Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Piqlout extends Activity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.piq);

    Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);


    if (next.getText().equals("Next")) {
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);



            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.piq2);
            Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
            next.setText("Prev");





        }
    });
    }
    if (next.getText().equals("Prev")){
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 ImageView img = (ImageView)     findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                 img.setImageResource(R.drawable.piq1);
                 Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
                 next.setText("Next");


        }
    });
    }
}

}
```

Here is my layout:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/piq1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="Next" />

  </FrameLayout>
```

What is happening is the first image is displayed with "next" button. When I click next the second image also comes and the button text changes to "prev". But then when I click prev nothing happens(the first image is not displayed). Please help me.

Comment: Remove the if statement when checking for Prev and attach it to the first if statement as else. Such that; if(next) { } else { }

Comment: nope. still the same thing is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Dont set text in XML.
2. Declare a string in your activity, setText and change it from there. An example:

   ```
   public class Piqlout extends Activity { 

   String s = "Next";
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.piq);

   Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
   next.setText(s);

   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
                         if (s.equals("Next")) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);               

           img.setImageResource(R.drawable.piq2);
           Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
                           s = "Prev"
           next.setText(s);
                         } else {
                            ImageView img = (ImageView)     findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.piq1);
                Button next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
                                    s = "Next"
                next.setText(s);
                         };            

       }
   });
   }

   }
   ```

It may have some error as I wrote it on my tablet.